# Eclipse plugin vs IntellJ plugin. What would be easier to develop?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, plugins

I know that IntellJ IDE is better than Eclipse for Java coding. But I have a hard time figuring out what would be easier to develop. An Eclipse plugin or an IntellJ plugin. Both have their own guidelines for plugin development but does anyone has any experience in plugin development to answer me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Would do you want to archive with your plugin?

General answer:
When I want to work with an existing code base - i.e. writing a plugin, first I take a look at the documentation to get a rough overview and then I get my fingers dirty as fast as possible.

I take an example or existing plugin that does something similar that I want to archive and I start to experiment.

So, try out both. One day writing/changing a simple Eclipse plugin and the other day doing the same with with IntelliJ platform.